# Sub declaration within lambda expression doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, lambda

I tried to run the following example from http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2429291&seqNum=8

```
Private progress As Progress(Of Integer)
Private counter As Integer = 0

Sub Main()
    Try
        progress = New Progress(Of Integer)
        AddHandler progress.ProgressChanged, Sub(sender, e)
                                                 Console.
                                                 WriteLine _
                                                 ("Download progress: " & _
                                                 CStr(e))
                                             End Sub

        DownloadAllFeedsAsync(progress)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    Finally
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Try
End Sub
```

My problem is, that the following line is not accepted by the compiler:

```
AddHandler progress.ProgressChanged, Sub(sender, e)
                                                     Console.WriteLine("Download progress: " & CStr(e))
                                                 End Sub
```

There seems to be a problem with `sender` and `e`.

The error message is the following:

**The Lambda-Parameter "sender" hides a variable in an embracing Block".**

Does somebody know this problem?

Comment: seems like there is `sender` variable outside of the lambda. Try renaming `sender`

Comment: This is working. Thanks for that, but I dont understand it.

Comment: Checked on both VS 2012 and 2017 and it's getting compiled without errors. As to your error message, please check this: [Lambda parameter '<parameter>' hides a variable in an enclosing block, a previously defined range variable, or an implicitly declared variable in a query expression.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc36641)

Comment: I am using VS 2013 and it doesn't work.

Comment: @MacieJ Los thanks for this advice. In the example from the link there is only a Sub Main() whereas in my example I  have Form1_Load(Sender As Object, e as Eventargs). So your link helped me because there is the Information that Sender and eventargs must be unique names in the same scope. Thanks.

Comment: If this resolves your issue, can i post my comment as an answer? Then you'll be able to accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i mentioned in my comment to the question: i've checked related code on both VS: 2012 and 2017 and it's getting compiled without errors.

As to your error message, please check this: [Lambda parameter '' hides a variable in an enclosing block, a previously defined range variable, or an implicitly declared variable in a query expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc36641)

The most important thing is:

> **To correct this error**
>
> ```
> Ensure that all variables in your lambda expression have unique 
> names that do not duplicate existing variable names in the same scope.
> ```

Accordingly to your comment:

> In the example from the link there is only a `Sub Main()` whereas in my
>   example I have `Form1_Load(Sender As Object, e as Eventargs)`.

So, variables: `sender` and `e` are existing in the same scope. Now, you know what to do to resolve your issue ;)